# Action must be plain object. Use custom middleware

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, redux-thunk

**What would be the problem?**

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

**Configure Store:**

```
export default configureStore = () => {
  let store = compose(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))(createStore)(reducers);
  return store;
}
```

**Action**

```
export const menulist = async ({ navigation  }) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: types.MENULIST_REQUEST_START })
        let response = await menuListByCategories();
        dispatch({ type: types.MENULIST_SUCCESS })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: types.MENULIST_FAILED })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As your error clearly states: action creators should return plain objects with `type` property and optional payload. Here you're returning a function that takes `dispatch` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using it the wrong way,

in Redux every action must return an object, and this is a must!
so, your dispatch, which is a function, should be called this way.

Besides you only need to declare async the function which returns dispatch. The async keyword determines that the following function will return a promise. As your first function (menulist) is returning the promise returned by the second function (dispatch one) you don't have to specify it.

```
export const menulist = ({ navigation  }) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: types.MENULIST_REQUEST_START })
        let response = await menuListByCategories();

        dispatch({ type: types.MENULIST_SUCCESS })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: types.MENULIST_FAILED })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now no error. But it's not entering inside the block.

Comment: inside the try catch? Is it properly connected in your container? any errors?

Comment: Yes.  Its getting called. But nothing happening

Comment: This seems to be out of scope of the question. Either way I can't help you more without more info, have you tried using redux-logger to see what is happening?

Comment: menuListByCategories was not called properly. Thanks. Its worked.